# i want read date from the file name and keep last 5 dates files using powershell

Tags: powershell

i have set of files in a specific folder,
i want read date from the file name, 
select last 2 dates files and move all other dates files to another location using powershell

below is the file name sample i have

```
Directory: E:\HOLDS\trim
Name                        
----                        
17988000412767900-20170402-T
17988000412770804-20170402-T
17988000412773204-20170402-T
17988000412792005-20170402-T
17988000412794300-20170402-T
17991325988242500-20170403-C
17991325988242800-20170403-C
17991325988243000-20170403-C
17991325988245000-20170403-C
17991325988245200-20170403-C
17992327574130910-20170404-T
17992327574131100-20170404-T
17992327574145005-20170404-T
17992327574145209-20170404-T
17992327574169106-20170404-T
17993057054385600-20170405-T
17993326857390200-20170405-R
17993327575638604-20170405-T
17993327575676304-20170405-T
17993327575835705-20170405-T
17993327575844703-20170405-T
17997018695202606-20170409-T
17998001450000100-20170409-C
17998001450001000-20170409-C
17998057920002100-20170409-R
17998119423714112-20170410-T
17998119423728401-20170410-T
17998282230003400-20170409-R
17998297810002500-20170409-R
17998327575543207-20170410-T
17998327575543708-20170410-T
17998327575546104-20170410-T
17998327575547600-20170410-T
17998327575591805-20170410-T
```

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43530400/edit) your question to provide us with the code showing what you have tried. Be sure to include whatever errors you received, or explain how it did not accomplish what you expected.

Answer (score 0):

is there any reason why you can't filter by the last write time instead?

```
$sourcedir = "c:\scripts\"

$files = get-childitem $sourcedir | sort LastwriteTime

# last files
$files[-1].name
# second from last file
$files[-2].Name
```

Comment: thanks for the code. i cannot select by last write time since the file mignt get generated with future date in file name

Answer (score 0):

From your requirement, if your file name is always follow same style, I think you can do this with this flow:
1. Define an Direcroty/Map which is an 
2. Get all the files, then loop the files & split the file name with '-' & take the second as date, then add the  into the directory/map
3. Move all files which not satisfied condition out

```
$maps = New-Object 'system.collections.generic.dictionary[[string],[system.collections.generic.list[string]]]';
$list = New-Object 'system.collections.generic.list[string]';

$files = ("17988000412767900-20170402-T",
"17988000412770804-20170402-T",
"17988000412773204-20170402-T",
"17988000412792005-20170402-T",
"17988000412794300-20170402-T",
"17991325988242500-20170403-C",
"17991325988242800-20170403-C",
"17991325988243000-20170403-C",
"17991325988245000-20170403-C",
"17991325988245200-20170403-C",
"17992327574130910-20170404-T",
"17992327574131100-20170404-T",
"17992327574145005-20170404-T",
"17992327574145209-20170404-T",
"17992327574169106-20170404-T",
"17993057054385600-20170405-T",
"17993326857390200-20170405-R",
"17993327575638604-20170405-T",
"17993327575676304-20170405-T",
"17993327575835705-20170405-T",
"17993327575844703-20170405-T",
"17997018695202606-20170409-T",
"17998001450000100-20170409-C",
"17998001450001000-20170409-C",
"17998057920002100-20170409-R",
"17998119423714112-20170410-T",
"17998119423728401-20170410-T",
"17998282230003400-20170409-R",
"17998297810002500-20170409-R",
"17998327575543207-20170410-T",
"17998327575543708-20170410-T",
"17998327575546104-20170410-T",
"17998327575547600-20170410-T",
"17998327575591805-20170410-T");

$files | %{
$date = $_.Split('-')[1];
if($maps.Keys.Contains($date)){
    $maps[$date].Add($_);
}
else{
    $maps.Add($date, $list);
    $maps[$date].Add($_);
}
}
```

The output will be:

```
Key   : 20170402
Value : {17988000412767900-20170402-T, 17988000412770804-20170402-T, 17988000412773204-20170402-T, 17988000412792005-20170402-T...}

Key   : 20170403
Value : {17988000412767900-20170402-T, 17988000412770804-20170402-T, 17988000412773204-20170402-T, 17988000412792005-20170402-T...}

Key   : 20170404
Value : {17988000412767900-20170402-T, 17988000412770804-20170402-T, 17988000412773204-20170402-T, 17988000412792005-20170402-T...}

Key   : 20170405
Value : {17988000412767900-20170402-T, 17988000412770804-20170402-T, 17988000412773204-20170402-T, 17988000412792005-20170402-T...}

Key   : 20170409
Value : {17988000412767900-20170402-T, 17988000412770804-20170402-T, 17988000412773204-20170402-T, 17988000412792005-20170402-T...}

Key   : 20170410
Value : {17988000412767900-20170402-T, 17988000412770804-20170402-T, 17988000412773204-20170402-T, 17988000412792005-20170402-T...}
```

Then you can order the $map and loop all the files in it's value & move them out.

Comment: thanks for the code.. will try this method and share the feedback

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 $yourdirpath="C:\Temp\yourfolder"
 $yourmovedir="C:\Temp\movedir"
 $numrow=0
 $currentdate=""

 Get-ChildItem $yourdirpath | 
  select FullName, @{N="DateFile";E={$_.Name.substring(18, 8)}} |
   sort DateFile -Descending | 
    foreach{

         if ($_.DateFile -ne $currentdate)
         {
             $numrow++
             $currentdate=$_.DateFile
         }

         [pscustomobject]@{FullName=$_.FullName;DateFile=$_.DateFile;numrow=$numrow}

    } | where numrow -gt 2 | foreach{move-item $_.FullName -Destination $yourmovedir }
```

Comment: hi thanks for the help. it works. what if i want select the count from backward. its must be -18,8?

Comment: try .substring(0, 17)

Comment: when i give 0 it starts to count from left. i want start the count from right side.